# How to create an array of unicode values of currency symbols in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

```
Unicode values are:
U+20A0 to U+20AF
```

All these values represent currency symbol. Check the following link for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_Symbols_(Unicode_block)

In swift, I can print the currency symbol associated with a unicode with the following code:

```
let rupee = "\u{20B9}"    //Its currency symbol "₹"
```

My goel is to show all currency symbols in a table and for this purpose, I want to create an array of unicode values whose range I have mentioned above. I have used the following code to create an array, but there is problem in the step in which I am creating the unicode :

```
var unicodeArray:[String] = [String]()
for var decNumber=0; decNumber < 16; decNumber++ {
    let hexVal = String(decNumber, radix: 16)
    let unicode = "{20A\(hexVal)}"  \\u is missing in the string, writing \u gives error"
    unicodeArray.append(unicode)
}
```

After the for loop, array would have values between {20A0} to {20AF}, But I need the values from "\u{20A0}" to "\u{20AF}". How can I fix this. Or Is there any other way of doing what I am trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited: Used swift style loop as per suggestion @Grimxn**

Try this:

```
var unicodeArray:[String] = [String]()
for decNumber in 0..<16 {
    let hexVal = String(decNumber, radix: 16)
    let integer = Int(strtoul("20A\(hexVal)", nil, 16))
    let unicode = UnicodeScalar(integer)

    unicodeArray.append(String(unicode))
}
```

Basically it prepares the hex values as `Int`. Then `UnicodeScalar` converts them to unicode. Which you can then convert into a `String`.

Comment: Upvoted, but don't use C-style `for` loops - they are deprecated and will disappear in Swift 3. Use `for decNumber in 0 ..< 16 {` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, you can use the following Playground sample code in order to get an array of all currency symbols as they are defined in Currency Symbols Unicode block:

```
//1.
let scalarRange: ClosedRange<Unicode.Scalar> = "\u{20A0}" ... "\u{20BF}"
//2.
let scalarValueRange = scalarRange.lowerBound.value ... scalarRange.upperBound.value

//3.
let currencySymbolArray = scalarValueRange.compactMap({ (scalarValue: UInt32) -> String? in
    guard let scalar = Unicode.Scalar(scalarValue) else { return nil }
    return String(scalar)
})

print(currencySymbolArray)
/*
 prints: ["₠", "₡", "₢", "₣", "₤", "₥", "₦", "₧", "₨", "₩", "₪", "₫", "€", "₭", "₮", "₯", "₰", "₱", "₲", "₳", "₴", "₵", "₶", "₷", "₸", "₹", "₺", "₻", "₼", "₽", "₾", "₿"]
 */
```

1. You first create a range of Unicode scalars that match the code points for Currency Symbols.
2. Because this first range is not strideable (you can't iterate on it), convert it to a range of Unicode scalar numeric representations using `Unicode.Scalar`'s [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2908540-value) `property`.
3. Iterate over your range in order to create a `String` from each Unicode scalar numeric representation so that you can get an array of Currency Symbols.

---

If needed, the following code uses `Unicode.Scalar`'s [`escaped(asASCII:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2906186-escaped) in order to get an array of Currency Symbols represented as ASCII escaped numeric values:

```
let scalarRange: ClosedRange<Unicode.Scalar> = "\u{20A0}" ... "\u{20BF}"
let scalarValueRange = scalarRange.lowerBound.value ... scalarRange.upperBound.value

let currencySymbolArray = scalarValueRange.compactMap({ (scalarValue: UInt32) -> String? in
    guard let scalar = Unicode.Scalar(scalarValue) else { return nil}
    let ascii = scalar.escaped(asASCII: true)
    return ascii
})

print(currencySymbolArray)
/*
 prints: ["\\u{20A0}", "\\u{20A1}", "\\u{20A2}", "\\u{20A3}", "\\u{20A4}", "\\u{20A5}", "\\u{20A6}", "\\u{20A7}", "\\u{20A8}", "\\u{20A9}", "\\u{20AA}", "\\u{20AB}", "\\u{20AC}", "\\u{20AD}", "\\u{20AE}", "\\u{20AF}", "\\u{20B0}", "\\u{20B1}", "\\u{20B2}", "\\u{20B3}", "\\u{20B4}", "\\u{20B5}", "\\u{20B6}", "\\u{20B7}", "\\u{20B8}", "\\u{20B9}", "\\u{20BA}", "\\u{20BB}", "\\u{20BC}", "\\u{20BD}", "\\u{20BE}", "\\u{20BF}"]
 */
```

---

As an alternative, you can use `String`'s [`init(_:radix:uppercase:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init) to convert the scalar value to an hexadecimal value:

```
let scalarRange: ClosedRange<Unicode.Scalar> = "\u{20A0}" ... "\u{20BF}"
let scalarValueRange = scalarRange.lowerBound.value ... scalarRange.upperBound.value

let currencySymbolArray = scalarValueRange.map({ (scalarValue: UInt32) -> String in
    return String(scalarValue, radix: 16, uppercase: true)
})

print(currencySymbolArray)
/*
 prints: ["20A0", "20A1", "20A2", "20A3", "20A4", "20A5", "20A6", "20A7", "20A8", "20A9", "20AA", "20AB", "20AC", "20AD", "20AE", "20AF", "20B0", "20B1", "20B2", "20B3", "20B4", "20B5", "20B6", "20B7", "20B8", "20B9", "20BA", "20BB", "20BC", "20BD", "20BE", "20BF"]
 */
```